# iscroll 5 beta doesn't show scrollbars

Tags: iscroll

i'm implementing iScroll 5 beta on my site but have a problem to show and customize horizontal scrollbar. In the options I have scrollX: true and this enables to scroll horizontally but there is no scrollbar for that.  On the demo sites of iScroll 5 beta there are no scrollbars (on desktop).

Did anybody manage to show and customize them?

Thanks,
Arek

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `scrollbars: true` as an option when initialising `IScroll`. it will add it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I resolved that but getting more into iscroll 5 code. Iscroll 5 is more complicated and I used 'indiscator option' to manage scrollbars: 

indicators: {
   el: document.getElementById('indicator'),
   resize: false,
   interactive: true,   
   freeScroll: true,
   speedRatioY: 2
  }});

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below options to make it work for all the browsers and Mobile devices.

```
{
    scrollbars: true,
    hideScrollbar: true, // Important for Firefox
    fadeScrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    click: true,
    disablePointer: true, // Important for Android devices
    disableTouch: false,
    disableMouse: false,
}
```