# scrollIntoView - how to make it work in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading my site into an iFrame that's on another site. I'd like to scroll to the top of an element within that iFrame. I'm using the Javascript code below:

```
 document.getElementById("cart-wrapper").scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto' });
```

This works perfectly on desktop browsers, however it doesn't work at all on iOS mobile (I've tested Safari and Chrome). I've tried the smooth scroll polyfill (https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) but that doesn't work either (I've basically included `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>`) )

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you are responsible of *siteB* which is loaded from *siteA* inside an <iframe> and wish the iframe content only to scroll to `#cart-wrapper`, which is obviously part of *siteB*. Is that right?

Comment: Can't repro on Android (both Chrome and Firefox). Can you confirm you do experience the issue with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52nsc0ub/)  on  your device? And if not, do you with [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/52nsc0ub/1/)?

Comment: @Kaiido that's right.

Comment: You can reproduce with both fiddles?

Answer (score 0):

Few days back , I was also facing this issue. I fixed it with iScroll

I tried [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)

I would be able to help  you, if you need any

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the code below; I can see iscroll is being loaded successfully, but no scrolling actually occurs. Am I doing something wrong?

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script>
var myScroll;
myScroll = new IScroll('#cart-wrapper', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });
myScroll.scrollToElement( document.querySelector('#cart-wrapper') );
</script>

Comment: const elementOffsetTop = parseInt(document.getElementById(getIDFromHash).offsetTop || 0, 10); myScroll.scrollTo(0, -elementOffsetTop, 500);

Comment: {
    scrollbars: true,
    hideScrollbar: true, // Important for Firefox
    fadeScrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    click: true,
    disablePointer: true, // Important for Android devices
    disableTouch: false,
    disableMouse: false,
}

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398501/iscroll-5-beta-doesnt-show-scrollbars/55015210#55015210

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfortunately it still doesn't work in the iFrame (no scrolling happens) even after adding the code you mentioned

Comment: I think the problem might be in the wrapper element. i.e. myScroll = new IScroll('body'... - 'body' works if I own the host page that the iFrame sits in, but otherwise it doesn't

Comment: yes, the scroll is applied to the firstchild of the hosted element